# filter XML data from a page to get specific data out

Tags: python, xml

I have the following xml data that i want to filter and just get the string in between Name. I tried using `xml.etree.ElementTree` but no luck so far. Is there a good way to remove all this and just get the string output?

```
 ParentList
  Name xyz-abc-01 /Name 
  Name xyz-abc-02 /Name 
  ParentList
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

my_tree = '<ParentList><Name>xyz-abc-01</Name><Name>xyz-abc-02</Name></ParentList>'
for name_element in my_tree.getchildren():
    print name_element.text
```

You can access any child elements within a tree like this.